# Bounding $x+y$ above and below by using $xy$

Tags: inequality

Given $xy = C$ for integers $x, y\in \mathbb{Z}$, let's suppose that we want to maximize or minimize $x+y$. Which we do by observing that

$$x+y = \pm\sqrt{(x-y)^2 + 4xy} = \pm\sqrt{(x-y)^2 + 4C} = \pm\sqrt{|x-y|^2 + 4C}$$

Thus $|x+y|$ is larger as $|x-y|$ gets larger. Is there a more straightforward way to bound $x+y$ below and above by using $xy$?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks, edited

Comment: Given $xy = C$, $x-y$ is largest when one of $x = C$ and the other $y = 1$. The minimum is when $x = y = \sqrt{C}$. Converted to integers appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but to long for a comment.

For the maximum,

Lets take $x < y$ then

For reals we have :

If $xy = 1$ then $x+y$ is unbounded.

For instance $x = 10^{100} , y = 10^{-100} , xy = 1$

We just minimize $x$.

But you ask for integers.

Well that is simple too.

Say $xy = 100$

Again we minimize $x$.

then we can get $x+y = 101$ because $x = 1, y = 100$

So in general we get $C+1$ as maximum by picking $x=1$.

Notice that if $xy = C$ we have

$x = 1, y = C$ gives $C+1$.

If $x = 2$ (is valid) we get $2y = C$ and $x + y = 2 + C/2$

If $x = 3$ (is valid) we get $3y = C$ and $x + y = 3 + C/3$

etc

So $x = 1$ is optimal.

EDIT : A bit more formal :

Let $C > 2$ and $x < y$
,
$xy = C$
,
$x < C$

Then $x + y = x + C/x$

Since $x < y$, we have $x < C/x$

This means the biggest part of $x + C/x$ is the part $C/x$.

So to maximize $x + C/x$ we maximize $C/x$.

Maximizing $C/x$ is the same as minimizing $x$.

Hence $x=1$.

Similarly the minimum of $x + y$, is the minimum of $x + C/x$.

Since $x < y$, we have $x < C/x$

This means the biggest part of $x + C/x$ is the part $C/x$.

So to minimize $x + C/x$ we minimize $C/x$.

Min $C/x$ is the same as maximizing $x$.

Since $x < y$ we get the maximum of $x$ when $x$ is near $y$

This occurs when $x=y$ or almost.

Since $xy = C$ this implies $x$ is as close to $ \sqrt C$ as possible.

By symmetry this implies that $y$ is also trying to be close to the sqrt of $C$.

If $ C $ has many divisors they could both be close the the sqrt of $C$ and then we the estimate $ x + y$ is about $2 \sqrt C$.

But for example $125 = 5^3 $ gives us

$125 = x y = 5^2 5$

and $x + y = 25  + 5 = 30$ and $30 > 2 \sqrt 125 > 2 * 11.18.. > 22$

Comment: edited the answer @AdamRubinson